# Does Kinect for windows v2 work with Parallels?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, kinect, parallels

Does Kinect for windows v2 work on mac pro using windows 8.1 that is running on top of Parallels?

Comment: some dummy did -1 on this, it's a useful question and an answer, +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

Considering Kinects v2's minimum hardware requirements below (copied from [this MSDN blogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn791991.aspx)), it is not possible for windows 8/8.1 running on top of Parallels to recognize and run Kinect v2. The latest version of parallels v10, as of the time of this answer, only supports DirectX 10 which is below the minimum requirement. I have tried it myself, but no success even with Parallels Gaming Mode. Moreover, in order for Kinect to be recognized you need the full USB 3.0 bandwidth.

Alternative solution as discussed in[this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kinectforwindows/archive/2014/07/28/developing-with-kinect-v2-on-a-mac.aspx), is to use WindowsToGo or by installing Windows using boot camp.

Kinects v2 minimum required capabilities:

1. 64 bit (x64) processor
2. 4 GB Memory (or more)
3. I7 3.1Ghz (or higher)
4. Built-in USB 3.0 host controller (Intel or Renesas chipset).
   If you’re adding USB 3.0 functionality to your existing PC through an adapter, please ensure that it is a Windows 8 compliant device and that it supports Gen-2. See the troubleshooting section of Getting Started for more information.
5. DX11 capable graphics adapter (see list of known good adapters below)
   Intel HD 4400 integrated display adapter
   ATI Radeon HD 5400 series
   ATI Radeon HD 6570
   ATI Radeon HD 7800 (256bit GDDR5 2GB/1000Mhz)
   NVidia Quadro 600
   NVidia GeForce GT 640
   NVidia GeForce GTX 660
   NVidia Quadro K1000M
6. A Kinect v2 sensor, which includes a power hub and USB cabling.